# Possible to speed up server clock?

Tags: linux

I want to run an interactive simulation and have time pass at 12x real time.  There is more than one solution to this, but is there a way to make the server clock run 12x faster?

Comment: Which server OS are we talking about here?

Comment: Linux - current server is Ubuntu Hardy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624137/simulating-faster-time-in-linux) (although Java-based). Even if you could speed the system clock up you'd break various of things (logging, timestamps on files, time-based kernel stuff to name but three) so it would seem better if your code could be made independent of "real" time.

Perhaps you could invent a new unit of time, equal to 1/12 of a second, and code your app in terms of that?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a script that changes the clock (starting waaaay back) and every second adds +12 seconds won't be good, will it? Somewhat I suspect the application is not using gettimeofday, but has an internal counter and timers. 
What simulation is that?

Comment: It will be a django system with people trading with each other.  Can fudge it, but just wondering if it's possible to make the server solve the problem.

Comment: Must admit no familiarity with Django trading systems :)
I suspect it would not help, since it involves other peers (do you plan to adjust their clock as well?). Again, sorry for not being of much help - best thing would be tweaking the simulation for that purpose, assuming it's possible at all.

Comment: It does seem possible to tweek the clock - see adjtime - but maybe not advisable!

Answer (score 0):

Try [adjtime](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/apis/adjtime.htm)

Comment: This looks fun and will play with it - but am heading advice of answer above that warns of all the things I'll screw up if I mess with the click.  Still if I use an new Amazon instance for each test that wouldn't matter....  Thanks for finding this.

Comment: `adjtime` is not that helpful in your case, because it applies its changes over a long period of time. It's more suited to sync'ing the system clock to an external time source.